# Set Password On Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created an app in C# and using SQL Server 2012. I want to deploy a project to a target machine and I want to set a password on only one database so that  only those people will have direct access to the database on SQL Server who have the password.

How to perform this? Any help please?

Server is running in Windows Auth Mode

Comment: thinking about security, permissions and roles should have been done at the start of your project!

Comment: @MitchWheat I am a beginner so I didn't have the thought...What to Do now?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change your Sql Server windows authentication mode to Mixed mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188670.aspx

Once you modified to Mixed mode you can create new logins under Server>security>logins.

[image: Logins]

Comment: I have Tried this @Roshan but when windows admin starts SQL server it asks weather to login using windows authentication or SQl server auth. When he selects windows auth, he is able to access the database without password

Comment: @Khan, you cannot prevent a sysadmim role member from accessing a SQL Server database.  Windows admins are not necessarily sysadmin role members but may be provisioned as such.

Comment: @Khan It's not possible to disable windows authentication mode. SQL Server supports only two modes:
--Windows authentication only
--Mixed mode (windows authentication and SQL Server authentication)

You can limit access via windows authentication by restricting (or removing) the permissions of the windows users/groups with logins in SQL Server.

Comment: Ok.. but what would be the best solution for me if i don't want to show database to the windows admin? is There any? or even if a table can be protected its good